# Calculating expected mean difference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, effect-size

Let's say I have two samples (pre-test, post-test) with $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$.

Their difference is significant at $\alpha=0.26$ (but not lower). If I understood it correctly that means that there is a 26% chance that there is no difference between the two distributions the samples came from and 74% that the post-test sample came from a different distribution.

Can I say that

$E[\mu_1-\mu_0]=0\alpha+(1-\alpha)(\mu_1-\mu_0)=0.74(\mu_1-\mu_0)$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is a 26% chance
>   that there is no difference between the two distributions the samples
>   came from and 74% that the post-test sample came from a different
>   distribution.

Not exactly. This is a Bayesian statement and there is no such statement in frequentist analysis. The real interpretation is: "if the two samples came from the same population, there would be 26% chances to see at least such a difference and 74% chances to see less difference". But honestly, your statement is not so bad for **intuitive** understanding.

Sadly not to derive formulas...

> Can I say that E[μ1−μ0]=0α+(1−α)(μ1−μ0)=0.74(μ1−μ0)

No.

There is no distribution of the true parameters in frequentist analysis and hence the expectation E[μ1−μ0]  (where I guess these would be the true hidden parameters) can't be defined. You need Bayes to define it. The expression would depend on the prior and kind of data.